# Change Option Value (Time) if the Value reach its limit on a certain date using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of Time in google script and it is reflected in the Web App. I got it from youtube.com. Here is the screen shot of the web app and the google sheet.

Web App:

[image]

google sheet (Sheet Name: "Time_Select"):

[image]

These codes were used to generate or output the time in html using javascript and google script.

html code:

```
          <div class="input-field col s4">
             <select id="subTime">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your preferred time</option>
                <?!= list1; ?> 
             </select>
             <label>Select Time</label>
          </div> <!-- CLOSE TIME FIELD -->
       </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->
```

from the html code above, this was inserted to populate the list from the google sheet.

javascript:

```
<?!= list1; ?>
```

google script:

```
function doGet(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws1 = ss.getSheetByName("Time_Select");
  var list1 = ws1.getRange(1,1,ws1.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var htmlListArray1 = list1.map(function(r){return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join(''); 

  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("test");
  tmp.list1 = htmlListArray1; 
  return tmp.evaluate();

}
```

Now, my problem is how can I change the the value of the time in the list if it reached my selection limit. By the way, here is the output data if you selected the time and date in my web app.

output google sheet (Sheet Name: "Test_Data")

[image]

From the data above, the 8AM and 9AM reached 3 times on a certain date, I would like to change it to "this time was full, please select another one".

To sum it up I want to check if the time on a certain date reached the limit then change the time selection to "this time was full, please select another one".

I tried to add another function which checks the if the time with specific date reached the limit but cannot change the time value in selection:

```
function timeLimit(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Test_Data");
  var dataRg = ws.getRange(1, 7, ws.getLastRow(), 2).getValues(); 
  var myData = [];


  var CheckLimitReached = function (T)
  {
    var records= {};
    T.forEach(function (x) { records[x] = (records[x] || 0) + 1; });
    var limit_reached = Object.keys(records).filter(function (R) {
      return records[R] >= 3;});
    //return limit_reached;
    Logger.log(limit_reached);
  };
   var dataDisable = CheckLimitReached(dataRg);
  Logger.log(dataDisable);

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? Is your current issue is the function of `timeLimit()`? If it's so, can you provide the sample values of `dataRg` and `dataDisable` you want to achieve? By this, I would like to think of the issue and solution. And if you can do, also can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Because in your screen shot, I cannot understand about the types of the values of cells.

Comment: @Tanaike here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lEfzjG1zzJVPMN8r-OpeZm6q9_IqSwk9DNCEY-q7ozY/edit?usp=sharing  the log for dataRg: `[19-08-07 13:14:15:863 HKT] [[Scheduled Date, Scheduled Time], [Wed Aug 07 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 8:00 AM], [Wed Aug 07 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 9:00 AM], [Wed Aug 07 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 10:00 AM], [Wed Aug 07 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 8:00 AM], [Wed Aug 07 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 8:00 AM], [Thu Aug 08 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 9:00 AM], [Wed Aug 07 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2019, 9:00 AM]]'

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing a sample Spreadsheet. I could understand about the input values. As the next step, I would like to know the output values you want. So can I ask you about the value of `dataDisable` you want?

Comment: @Tanaike As you can see in the sheet names below, there is this "Time_Select" which will be the input value under column Scheduled Time of the sheet name "Test_Data". Do you think it is possible that if the Time on a certain date reached 3 times, it will disable the time in the selection for that said date only?

Comment: I'm thinking of adding `document.getElementById("subDate").addEventListener("input",checkTime);` and function for `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateTime).timeLimit();`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. 1. I couldn't understand about the relationship between `dataDisable` and the sheet of `Time_Select`. 2. I couldn't understand about the relationship between `oogle.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateTime).timeLimit()` and your current issue.

Comment: @Tanaike My apologies. Time_Select is the source of my selection which is displayed in the html or my web application. `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateTime).timeLimit()` is the code in the javascript to call out the function in google script and will return a value in javascript

Comment: If you will notice on my question I have a screenshot of web app. and the time that was displayed there comes from the sheetname "Time_Select".

Comment: Thank you for replying. About the returned values of `dataDisable` at the function of `timeLimit()`, what value do you want?

Comment: I'm having a problem in how to disable or change the time in the my option if the for a certain date only. Example if August 7, 2019 and 8AM exists 3 times, the 8AM option in my web app will be disabled or change into other values if someone selects the August 7, 2019 date. But if someone select August 8, 2019 for example, the 8AM option will still exist. Is it possible? thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. I had thought that your issue is in `timeLimit()`. But it seems that my understanding was not correct. I apologize for my poor English skill. If I could correctly understand your question, I would like to think of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Try the following workflow:

The `doGet()` function returns an HTML webpage

-> The webpage has a dropdown to choose a date

-> On submit buton click a JS function will be called that passes the selected date into the `.gs` part of the code

-> In `.gs` an Apps Script function checks which time slots are still available for the chosen date

-> A second dropdown menu in the Web page , containing times, will be dynamically populated with a list of time slots available for this specific date

**More in detail:**

> in HTML

- implement a list / other selection method for the date combined with a submit button:

```
<select id="Date">
 <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your preferred day</option>
    ...
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="passDate()" value="Confirm date">
```

- Write in the `<script></script>` part of the HTML file a `passDate()` function, that passes the selected option to an Apps Script function:

```
function passDate(date){
var dropdown=document.getElementById('Date');
var date=dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).timeLimit(date);
  }
```

> Apps script:

- Write a `timeLimit(date)` function that finds all already reserved time slots for the specific `date` in `Test_Data`:

```
function timeLimit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Test_Data");
  var dataRg = ws.getRange(1, 7, ws.getLastRow(), 2).getValues(); 
  var myData = [];
  for(var i=0;i<dataRg.lenth:i++){
   if(dataRg[0][i]==date){
    myData.push(dataRg[1][i])
    }
   }
```

- Find the time values that occur more than the allowed limit by writing a function that detects the occurrence of each element in an array:

```
function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    var indexes = [], i = -1;
    while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i+1)) != -1){
        indexes.push(i);
    }
    return indexes;
}
```

- And run it for each of the possible time slots retrieved from `Time_Selec`t, testing if the occurrence is higher than the allowed limit and pushing only the time slots that have not reached the limit into  `htmlListArray1`:

```
 var ws1 = ss.getSheetByName("Time_Select");
 var list1 = ws1.getRange(1,1,ws1.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
 var limit=3;
 var htmlListArray1 = []
for (var j=0;j<list1.length;j++){
  if(!getAllIndexes(myData, list1[0][j]).length>=limit){
  htmlListArray1.push('<option>' + list1[0][j] + '</option>'; }); 
   }
  }
  htmlListArray1.join(''); 
  return htmlListArray1; 
  }
```

- Implement the `onSuccess()` function in JS in the

> `<script></script>`part of the HTML

file where the list with active options will be dynamically inserted from the return value of `function timeLimit()` into the dropdown menu:

```
function onSuccess(htmlListArray1) {        
        document.getElementById('subTime').innerHTML = htmlListArray1;
      }
```

### When you you open your time selection dropdown - only a list with the available time slots will appear.

Note: Please adjust your `doGet()` function accordingly.

Comment: thank you. In the HTML part, you mean to add options on the html code and not to get in the google sheet? and in the app script part, I should create functions like the one you stated and change my `doGet()` function as what you have showed above? Sorry I'm a bit confused but thank you for the help

Comment: I'm getting this error: `ReferenceError: "getAllIndexes" is not defined.`. I tried to call the function but still same error.

Comment: The doGet() function is necessary for deploying a script as a Web App. It needs to contain `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("test");`, the rest goes into the `timeLimit()` function whre it will be dynamically called from the `JS function in the HTML part` . You reference error comes from the fact that some of the parameters you pass to the function are empty/not valid (maybe empty range?). Logs help to find the error.

Comment: So the code you modified which has `var limit=3;` and `htmlListArray1=[]` will now go to the `timeLimit()` function. sorry I'm a beginner in programming.

Comment: Also, how do you come up with `getAllIndexes(arr, val)` function, coz in the other code or function you never called that `getAllIndexes` function. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for my poor english. Im really a bit confused of your answer. :)

Comment: I also would like to ask why do you still have to access the `var ws1 = ss.getSheetByName("Time_Select");` if you already modified the html time selection option?

Comment: getAllIndexes() is an auxillary function that you call within the timeLimit() function: `if(!getAllIndexes(myData, list1[0][j]).length>=limit)` This means you push into `htmlListArray1` only the time slots for which the number of occurrences did not pass the limit.

Comment: as for `var ws1 = ss.getSheetByName("Time_Select");` - since you want the list of possible options be updated dynamically based on which options have been taken already, you need to compare every time the already taken time slots (in "Test_Data")  against the theoretically possible ones (in "Time_Select").

Comment: @ziganotchka Thank you. Not working for me. Maybe I didn't get the instructions right. Thank you so much

Comment: Just realized I had a typo it should be : function `passDate(date){...` instead of `passDate(){...` Should there still be problems - when you deploy the Web App,observe the console logs to debug the code: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/